# 'Error calling method on NPObject!' issue with removing a KML added through a network link

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I am adding a KMZ file through network link on a **ADD KMZ** button's onclick as follows  :-

```
var nlFile=null;
function addKMZData(){
    nlFile=ge.createNetworkLink('exampleKMLNL1');
    nlFile.setVisibility(true);
    var link = ge.createLink(" exampleLink1 ");
    link.setHref('http://localhost:8080/KMZs/example.kmz');
    nlFile.setLink(link);
    nlFile.setFlyToView(true);
    nlFile.setName('kmz');
    ge.getGlobe().getFeatures().appendChild(nlFile);
}
```

The 'example.kmz' file taken here contains a linestring placemark and the installed plugin version is 6.1.0.5001.

Then, I have a **REMOVE** button, clicking which removes the above added KMZ 's network link from the ge-plugin's instance. The following is the **REMOVE** button's onclick function :

```
function clearKMZData(){
    ge.getFeatures().removeChild(ge.getElementById('exampleKMLNL1'));
    nlFile=null;
}
```

These functions work well for the first time. But any attempt to add the same KMZ file using the addKMZData() function after removing the added KMZ network link, gives the error "Error calling method on NPObject!" at line 1 of the add function. Is this way of adding & removing KMZ/KML data through network links correct? Am I missing something in the above 2 JavaScript functions?

Regards,
Shiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as var nlFile is global

In your first function, change this

```
      nlFile=ge.createNetworkLink('exampleKMLNL1');
```

to this

```
      nlFile=ge.createNetworkLink('');
```

and change this

```
      function clearKMZData(){
          ge.getFeatures().removeChild(ge.getElementById('exampleKMLNL1'));
          nlFile=null;
      }
```

to this

```
      function clearKMZData(){
          ge.getFeatures().removeChild(nlFile);
      }
```

Comment: Thank you 'lifeIsGood' for replying. This worked. I also changed var link = ge.createLink(" exampleLink1 "); to var link = ge.createLink('');